# How to create multiple sip trunking based on pstn grouping using kamailio

Tags: sip, asterisk, kamailio

I have kamailio as load balancer and two asterisk machine as pstn gateway.

In dispatcher.list I have entry for both asterisk machine.
Sip trunking is established successfully between kamailio and asterisk.all working fine,

Is there any way to create multiple sip trunk for same kamailio server so that I can route call to different context based on the sip trunk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no "different context" in kamailio world.

You have config file. One config file. Config file for kamailio is actualy program which describe what to do.

You can put into config file check for ip address(static) or check of group via dispatcher ds_from_list or access group logic or sql query via avp_pairs. After that you can route via lcr or dispatcher  module. You can write any logic.